# Changing the background image of a UITableViewController Master of a UISplitViewController in Landscape orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uicollectionview, uinavigationitem

I have a simple app which is a combination of `UITableViewController`s, `UIViewController`s and `UISplitViewController`s. I am bringing the Landscape orientation to my iPad app now.

I have it configured so that the in Portrait, the `Master View` is hidden behind a `UIBarButtonItem` and in Landscape, the Master and Detail view are both showing. I have built custom themes within my app which changes the background and the `UINavigationBar` to match the selected theme.

**Issue**

When in Landscape and in the theme selection page, the Master view is the Menu (`UITableViewController`) and the Detail is the Theme selection page (`UICollectionView`). If I select a theme, the `UICollectionView` updates it's background immediately to represent the new theme. However, **the Master view does not update it's theme**. This is the issue.

In portrait mode, the Master is updated because in it's `viewWillAppear`, I have a call to the `changeAppThemes` method:

```
- (void)changeAppThemes
{    
    NSLog(@"This is getting called");
    self.selectedTheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Theme"];

    if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Mystical"])
    {
        ThemeManager *themeManager = [ThemeManager sharedManager];

        themeManager.backgrounds = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PurplepinkIPAD.png"]];       
        self.tableView.backgroundView = themeManager.backgrounds;
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepinknav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    }
```

Within my `didSelectMethod` of the `UICollectionView`, I have placed a call to the `changeAppThemes` method:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedTheme forKey:@"Theme"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 [self changeAppThemes];

 MasterTableViewController *master = [[MasterTableViewController alloc] init];
 [master changeAppThemes];
```

That is working in Landscape mode because the `NSLog` "`This is getting called`" is displayed. However, the themes are not changing.

If I change to Portrait Mode and back to Landscape, the theme is then updated.

It seems like it's missing one key element to be updated, even though I'm explicitly calling the `changeAppThemes` method from the `UICollectionView`.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the MasterTableViewController in detailView through this way if you create a UISplitViewController project with default setting through xcode.

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;
UINavigationController *controller = viewControllers[0];
MasterViewController * masterController = (MasterViewController *)controller.topViewController;
[masterController changeAppThemes];
```

Please make sure you get the masterController in your splitViewController's viewcontrollers instead of creating a new one, the new one is not inside splitViewController.

Comment: Thanks so much @gabbler - this answer worked perfectly and I'm so grateful for your assistance on this. It makes complete sense why this didn't work with my code because it was creating a new instance, instead of using the one in the splitView - this is brilliant. Thanks again and bounty happily awarded!